# Drawing a pattern using recursion in c++

Tags: c++

Im using c++ 14 and I trying to use recursion to draw the following pattern:
[Pattern I am trying to draw.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwcQ7.png)

```
void drawPattern(int width, int startcol){
  if (width > 0){
    for (int i=0; i<width; i++){
        cout << "*";
    }
    for (int i=0; i<startcol; i++){
        cout << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    drawPattern(width/2, startcol);
    drawPattern(width/2, startcol+1);
    for (int i=0; i<startcol; i++){
        cout << " ";
    }
    for (int i=0; i<width; i++){
        cout << "*";
    }
  }
}
```

I've always had trouble wrapping my head around recursion. This one has me stumped.

Comment: For this, I would start by doing it iteratively and get that working.  There is no real advantage on this particular task to recursion that I can see, so start with the easier.  Then, you can convert  your for loop to a recursive algorithm pretty easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image, we see the second half is just like first half except second half has started his position after the first half. First and last line draws n-th length '*' if n is the current length.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Draw(int pos, int len, bool fw) {
    cout << string(pos, ' ') << string(len, '*') << endl;
    if (len > 1) {
        Draw(pos, len / 2, true);
        Draw(pos + len / 2, len / 2, false);
    }
    cout << string(pos, ' ') << string(len, '*') << endl;
}

int main() {
    Draw(0, 8, true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that really helped!